# Append protobuf repeated field

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

```
message ColectionData
{
   repeated collection1 = 1;
   repeated collection2 = 2;
}
```

I am retrieving the data from message like,

```
auto collection = collectionData.collection1();
```

Now, I need to append this `collection` with `collectionData.collection2()`

Comment: collection.MergeFrom() ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by collection.MergeFrom()